# JQuery td:contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

So at work, I have to go through a list that contains thousands of users and select a checkbox by the ones I need to delete. Long story short it's a slow process. To make things faster I made this script to run in chrome using developer tools in the console.

```
var usernames = ["jimmy123"]; 
for(var i=0;i<usernames.length;i++)
{

    jQuery("td:containsExact("+usernames[i]")").find('[type=checkbox]').parent().attr('checked', true).css("background-color", "red");


}
var count = jQuery("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
alert("Everything Returned Okay!");
alert(usernames.length);
alert(count + " Checkboxes Checked!");
```

The Trouble is that let's say a user created 3 because they forgot the login for them "not uncommon" and their username is:
jimmy123
jimmy1234
jimmy12345

If I need to just check the box next to jimmy123 for removal my script selects all 3 since they have mostly the same username.I tried some filters but the result was the same.

[Backend Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvojU.jpg)

Comment: you need to provide sample html code

Comment: just provide the exact table like i have in my answer you should add the relevant table from your code where you are trying to make the checkboxes selected

Comment: i edited my answer see the **`EDIT`** section.

Comment: To clarify your question, you want to take an array of user names and automatically check a checkbox in an adjacent td?

Comment: Yes, but not check the ones with usernames that are similar it must be exact for this work.

Comment: do select the answer if it helped you out

Comment: updated the answer, and please mark it correct as the solution is already provided in the first attempt, it's just that you haven't been able to integrate according to your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`filter()`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function here to match the exact text in the `td` and then mark the checkbox selected. See the below script, you didn't provide the `HTML` so I added a sample table with some `td` containing usernames and checkbox, you should update the script accordingly

```js
$(function($) {
  var usernames = ["jimmy123", "omer"];
  for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
    $("tr>td").filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() == usernames[i]
    }).find('[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true).css("background-color", "red");
  }
  var count = jQuery("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
  console.log("Everything Returned Okay!");
  console.log("usernames.length" + usernames.length, usernames);
  console.log(count + " Checkboxes Checked!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox">omer</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox">omer123</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox">omer6565</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox">omer63645</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox">omer021</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox">omer521</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox">jimmy123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### `EDIT`

You can assign an `id` to your `table` say `my-table` and then change the selector in the code above from

```
$("tr>td").filter(function() {
```

to the following

```
$("#my-table tr>td").filter(function() {
```

The exact selector could be suggested when you add the `HTML` for your user listings that you are using the script with.

## `EDIT2`

According to your html it should be

```
$(function($) {
  var usernames = ["jimmy123", "omer"];
  for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
    $("#listContainer_datatable tr td").filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() == usernames[i]
    }).find('[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true).css("background-color", "red");
  }
  var count = jQuery("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
  console.log("Everything Returned Okay!");
  console.log("usernames.length" + usernames.length, usernames);
  console.log(count + " Checkboxes Checked!");
});
```

Comment: I can't really provide the website and it's contents unless I want to be unemployed LOL.

Comment: I will try your script 
Thanks for your help

Comment: haha @GodMan no issues you can see it working above and change the script according to your `HTML` structure, hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately I always get 0 Checkboxes Checked? But the Script seems to run fine it just does not select anything.

Comment: can you add the html structure for the table rows where you are displaying them you must be providing wrong selectors path @GodMan

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not able to edit the HTML of this page as far as I'm aware. I can make a picture of how the Table on the page is laid out so you can better understand. I will upload this later in the day.

Comment: you can add the screenshot of the `html` structure for the user list from the `HTMLInsepector` / developer console that would help @GodMan

Comment: this might help you understand what i am asking https://developer.chrome.com/devtools @GodMan

Comment: I added an image in my post

Comment: thats the frontend you have shown dude i am asking for the HTML code for this same table you have shown in the image , or have you assigned any `id` to the table you have shown ? @GodMan

Comment: I will post this later today apologies.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, College Finals. I've uploaded the backend screenshot above hope this helps.

Comment: open completely till its last child and add the screen grab here in comments, i need to look the tree for the username and the check box both  @GodMan

Comment: it would be rather more better if you right-click the main `table` and copy the contents in your post @GodMan

Comment: i wonder how hard it could be to provide the html structure for the table when asked for

Comment: Is the picture that I posted not everything you need?

Comment: This is what I get when I run your Edit 2 code in the Google Chrome Console.

ƒ ($) {
  var usernames = ["mercesdesjamerson"];
  for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
    $("#listContainer_datatable tr td").filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() == usernames[i]
 …

It does not check anything

Comment: @GodMan add the html i cant help like this i have been asking fron the start to add it but i dont know how hard it is for any one to understand the simple thing i have already provided the answer and you should be able to integrate it accordingly stackoverflow is not a coding service

Comment: I've posted an image above of what I thought you wanted. I marked your answer. I'll move on.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what you added was an image and not the **code** all you had to do was to rather than taking screenshot you could `right-click` on the table and copy the code in your question @GodMan , if you still cant get it, i cant help you out. just copy the code for `table` which lists the users and the checkboxes along with first an last name.